# Python correlation in DJango

Tags: python, django, pandas, apache-spark-sql

I am making a website on Django with Python. Index.html page has 4 inputs which are price1, price2, rating1, rating2. User will input data in HTML from there I am converting that data in Pandas data frame and trying to run correlation function `corr()`

Can someone help me to show complete correlation values in powershell?

My index.html code is as follows

```
    <html lang="en">
    <body>
    <form id='form' name='form' method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price1" name="price1" placeholder="Price">
    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price2" name="price1" placeholder="Price">
    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rating1" name="price1" placeholder="Price">
    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rating2" name="price1" placeholder="Price">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from home.models import Main, Seller
import pandas as pd

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            price1 = request.POST.get('price1')
            price2 = request.POST.get('price2')
            rating1 = request.POST.get('rating1')
            rating2 = request.POST.get('rating2')
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Price','Rating'], index=[0,1])
            df['Price'] = [price1, price2]
            df['Rating'] = [rating1, rating2]
            corr = df.corr()
            print(corr)
```

As I run this code it shows it says

```
Empty DataFrame
Column:[]
Index: []
```

Comment: Looking at your repetitive code: you should really make use of list.

Comment: also tried list but it is still showing the same result